# Definition of group scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Consider the definition of group scheme in *Stack Project* [[022R]](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/022R). In the paragraph following definition 39.4.1, it is said that

> We have morphisms of schemes over $S$: (identity) $e:S\rightarrow G$ and (inverse) $i:G\rightarrow G$ such that for every $T$ the quadruple $(G(T)=Hom(T,G),m,e,i)$ satisfies the axioms of a group listed above.

As for my intuition, the identity is the identity of $G(S)$, and the inverse is the inverse of $id : G\rightarrow G$ in $G(G)$. But I don't know how to check that $(G(T),m,e,i)$ is a group.

Comment: I think we must add one more condition : $G(\cdot)$ is a functor from category of schemes to category of groups.

Comment: Functoriality is automatic from the other conditions.  What does it mean how to ask whether a definition is satisfied when you don't have an example you want to check?

Comment: @LSpice Sorry to ask. How to show the functoriality? And forgive my pool English reading ability, I don't know what "What does it mean how to ask whether a definition is satisfied when you don't have an example you want to check?" means.

Comment: @LSpice I can show that now. Case closed.

Comment: You said "I don't know how to check that $(G(T), m, e, i)$ is a group", but the way you check that depends on what $G$ is.  So you can't check it until you've got an example in mind.

Comment: @LSpice I means how to check $e$ is the identity and $inv$ is the inverse by the $e$ and $i$ I give. Or if I am wrong, construct the right $e$ and $i$.

Comment: That's what it _means_ to say that "$(G(T), m, e, i)$ satisfies the axioms of a group listed above":  among other things, $e$ (or, rather, $e(*)$) is the identity and $i$ is the inverse map.  Checking that is part of checking that you've actually got a group scheme.  If you're *given* a group scheme, then this is part of the definition.  If you *think* you've got a group scheme, then you have to check it, and *how* you check it depends on what you've got.  So what example do you want to check?

Comment: @LSpice Let me clarify what I mean. In the definition of group schemes, we only know $(G(T),m)$ is a group without know what the identity and inverse is. Now let $e_0$ be the identity of $G(S)$ and $i_0: G \rightarrow G$ be the inverse of $id \in G(G)$. For arbitrary S-scheme $T$, let $e$ be the image of $e_0$ of the morphism induced by $T \rightarrow S$ and $i$ be the map $G(T) \rightarrow G(T)$ induced by $i_0$. I want to show that this $e$ is the identity of $G(T)$ and $i$ is the inverse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the condition that $m$ is a morphism of scheme. By that we can deduce $G(\cdot)$ is a functor.

Comment: Are you now satisfied with this answer, or do you want something more?